# associate multiple strings to only one

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to make an algorithm that easily simplifies and groups synonyms (with mismatches, capitals, acronims, etc) into only one. I supose there should exist a standard way to build such a structure that, looking for a string with possible mismatches, if the string exists in the structure, it returns a normalized string key. In short, sometimes the same concept could be written in several ways, but I only want to keep the concept.

For instance: Supose I want to normalize or simplify the appearances of

```
"General Director", "General Manager", "G, Dtor", "Gen Dir", ...
```

into

```
"GEN_DIR"
```

and keep only this result for further reference.

By the way, I suppose that building a Hash with key/value pairs like

```
hash["General Director"]="GEN_DIR"
hash["General Manager"]="GEN_DIR"
hash["G, Dtor"]="GEN_DIR"
hash["G, Dir"]="GEN_DIR"
```

could be a solution, but I suspect that there are more elegant or adequate solutions to that.

I would also need the way to persist this associative structure easily without any database because it should grow as I find more mismatches of the same word or sentence. A possible approach I think is to define this structure by means of a DSL, but I'm open to suggestions.

Comment: Even before thinking about coding, you have to show the rule that connects "General Director" etc. to "GEN_DIR"; that is your responsibility. If there is no such rule, then the only way you can do it is though matching it against a previously set dictionary, and that is typically done in ruby using a hash. Looking up via hash shows a good performance; you don't have to worry about the growth of a hash.

Answer (score 0):

Well, there is no rule, at least a clear one.

My aim is to scrap from web some "structured" data that sometimes is incorrectly or incompletely typed.  Some fields are descriptions and can be left as is. But some fields are suposedly to be "sets" but aren's correctly typed (as in my example). As a human can read that, he immediatelly knows what it means and can associate that with its meaning.

But I would like to automate as much as possible the process of reducing those possible mismatches to only one "string" (or symbol) before, for instance, saving it into a database. So, what I would need is a kindof hash or dictionary, as sawa correctly stated, that I can use to lookup any of such dirty strings  to get the normalized string or symbol.

Also, of course, it would be desirable a way to make this hash (or whatelse it could be) to learn from new mismatches in some way and add a new association automatically (possibly it could be based on a distance measure between mismatched string and normalized string that, if lower than X, a new association is built). The whole association (i.e, hash) should grow as new mismatches and concepts arise and, though, it should be kept anywhere (possibly in an xml file, or something like what Mori answered below) for future uses.

Any new Idea?